# js - track a moment when container has no child elements

Tags: javascript, html

I need to track a moment when certain html container has no child nodes. At this moment, some function has to be run.

For this markup:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="child square"></div>
  <div class="child square"></div>
  <div class="child square"></div>
  <div class="child square"></div>
  <div class="child square"></div>
</div>
```

each `square` gets removed on click:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var children = container.children;

[].map.call(children, function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.remove();
  })
});
```

and when my `container` is empty:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

I need to run some function, let's say

```
function isEmpty(){
  alert('container is empty');
}
```

How to do this ?
A pen: https://codepen.io/t411tocreate/pen/vWbrJW?editors=1111

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) is for you. It is made for such a case :

```
// new Observer
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      console.log(mutation.target.children.length);
      if (!mutation.target.children.length) {
        isEmpty()
      }
    }
  });    
});
// only observe childList changes
var config = { attributes: false, childList: true, characterData: false };
// start observation
observer.observe(container, config);
// switch off?
/* observer.disconnect(); */
```

You can observe your container as in https://codepen.io/sebilasse/pen/MOLXqw?editors=1111

It will always happen when the container is empty. It is not cluttered to a specific “user action” and so it also might help to avoid spaghetti code …

Answer (score 2):

You could check in callback if there are any child elements left

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var children = container.children;

[].map.call(children, function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.remove();
    if (children.length == 0) {
      empty();
    }
  })
});

function empty(){
  alert('container is empty');
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="child square">1</div>
  <div class="child square">2</div>
  <div class="child square">3</div>
  <div class="child square">4</div>
  <div class="child square">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
function isEmpty(){
if(container.querySelectorAll('.square').length==0)
  alert('container is empty');
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EbrRpN?editors=1111

Answer (score 1):

Add a check into the onclick function.

```
[].map.call(children, function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.remove();
    let remainingChildren = document.querySelectorAll('#container .child');
    if(remainingChildren.length == 0) {doSomething() };
  })
})
function doSomething() { // code goes here }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this in your event listener. You need to query on the children element count and alert accordingly.

[**WORKING DEMO**](https://codepen.io/nandukalidindi/pen/gXqKjd?editors=1111)

```
[].map.call(children, function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(){   
    this.remove();
    if(document.getElementById('container').children.length === 0) {
       alert('container is empty');
     }
  })
```